# How to use fingerprint sdk in java? Is there universal sdk for all fingerprint devices?

Tags: java, jna

I`m developing human resources software. I need to check attendence  of employees. We have ZKSoftware F702-s fingerprint device. And I need get information from it in java project. I searched for sdk and documentation how to use this sdk but I did not find anything. Help me whith my project. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found  dynamic libraries of my fingerprint device which activex component and I resolved my problem with JACOB is a JAVA-COM Bridge that allows you to call COM Automation components from Java. I call functions and handle events from library with Jacob.
 [Here is link to JACOB - Java COM Bridge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/)

Comment: JNA now includes some advanced COM support, including typelib-reading facilities.

Comment: @Guwanch could you post an example of calling a method within ZKFingerPrint SDK like `Connect_Net` using JACOB ?